# Sequelize hasOne association limitation

Tags: javascript, mysql, associations, sequelize.js

If `Member` and `MemberAddition` are models;

I created association like:

```
Member.hasOne(MemberAdditional);
MemberAddition.belongsTo(Member);
```

to create an one-to-one relation with auto-generated key MemberId

But how could I limit associated MemberAddition record to one.

I used build-in function to make associated:

```
// Used ES7 async/await
const member = await Member.create({ ... });
const addition1 = await MemberAddition.create({ ... });
const addition2 = await MemberAddition.create({ ... });

await addition1.setMember(member);
await addition2.setMember(member); // Should be failed or set addition1 MemberId null
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On you MemberAddition model add the field with the unique constraint.

```
memberId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  unique: true
}
```

Comment: If I have to set unique for auto-generated relative field, what different in hasMany and hasOne ?

Comment: I see what you mean, although i think the answer to that is: hasMany will add the getMemberAdditionals() to the instances of Member, and hasOne will add the getMember() to instances of MemberAdditional.
Maybe a good option was to pass for example: Member.hasOne(MemberAdditional, {through: { unique: true }}), but it seems the hasOne doesn't accept that option.

Comment: It's strange that hasOne doesn't automatically limit the number of instances to 1. Then there's no difference between it and hasMany